# Recyclerview content goes behind navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a typically problem since Android Lollipop. But I already tried everything. 
I have this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_selected"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_selected"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/filter_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_selected"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_selected"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_consoles_drawer"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the `activity_main_content` I have this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.robinstrutz.gamereleases.Activities.Activity_Main">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        android:transitionName="fab"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/raise"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my code I'm doing a typical initialization for a RecyclerView and nothing that changes the window settings/features or else. So now the content of my `RecyclerView` are going to the bottom of the screen behind the navigation bar. I already tried using `fitSystemWindows`, `clipToPadding` and `clipToChildren`.

I thought my style brings this fail but how it looks it doesn't:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>


    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFeatureSettings">smcp, onum</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.02</item>

</style>
```

Any suggestions how to fix this without adding `layout_marginBottom` to `RecyclerView`? Because of the height difference from the navigation bar on different devices.

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` inside `CoordinatorLayout` will help?

Comment: Can you provide snapshot?

Comment: @R.Zagórski Didn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

This could be the result of using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` when setting up the `Toolbar`.
With this setting on, the layout height below the Toolbar is larger than what is visible on your device. It includes some extra to allow smooth scrolling when the Toolbar is scrolled up.

If your Activity/Fragment does not need to scroll the content, a fix would be to simply remove the 'scroll' flag (`app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"`).